# Delete row based on another row value

Tags: jquery

I have 5 columns of table and want to delete 5th row data of any columns if its corresponding column in 6th row contains "No" or "Same". I think Jquery would do this. Please help me I am not pro in Jquery.
This is the code I tried but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr td:contains('Contract')").each(function() {
    $("tr:nth-child(5)").siblings('td').css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

The table looks like this:

```
Product    | Apple | Lenovo | HTC  | Samsung | LG
Camera     | 20MP  | 12MP   | 22MP | 20MP    | 20MP
RAM        | 4GB   | 4GB    | 4GB  | 3GB     | 2GB
Storage    | 32GB  | 32GB   | 32GB | 32GB    | 32GB
Expandable | No    | Yes    | No   | Yes     | Yes
Contract   | No    | Yes    | Same | Yes     | Yes
```

But I want the output like this:

```
Product    | Apple | Lenovo | HTC  | Samsung | LG
Camera     | 20MP  | 12MP   | 22MP | 20MP    | 20MP
RAM        | 4GB   | 4GB    | 4GB  | 3GB     | 2GB
Storage    | 32GB  | 32GB   | 32GB | 32GB    | 32GB
Expandable |       | Yes    |      | Yes     | Yes
Contract   | No    | Yes    | Same | Yes     | Yes
```

This is not a regular HTML table. It is generating in Survey analyzing software. It generates 8 tables in 8 pages, so I think jQuery will remove 5th row data if its corresponding 6th row data which contains 'No' or 'Same' at run time.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. When you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the *relevant* portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll be glad to try and help. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Team, Any update on my request?. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulJaleel Did you even bother to read the two comments?

Comment: Ben, I have changed my question as per your suggestions. Is it not fine now? Please let me know if anything to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `prev()` and `text()`, rather than hiding the entire `<td>`, for example:

```js
$('table tbody tr:nth-child(5)').find('td:contains(No),td:contains(Same)').each(function() {  
 $(this).parent('tr').prev().children('td').eq( $(this).index() ).text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Apple</th>
      <th>Lenovo</th>
      <th>HTC</th>
      <th>Samsung</th>
      <th>LG</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Camera</td>
      <td>20MP</td>
      <td>12MP</td>
      <td>22MP</td>
      <td>20MP</td>
      <td>20MP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RAM</td>
      <td>4GB</td>
      <td>4GB</td>
      <td>4GB</td>
      <td>3GB</td>
      <td>2GB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Storage</td>
      <td>32GB</td>
      <td>32GB</td>
      <td>32GB</td>
      <td>32GB</td>
      <td>32GB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Expandable</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contract</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Same</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```